# jQuery to handle the click event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="pagePermissions">Page Permissions:</label>                                            <br> <br>
  <table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Menu Page</th>
  <th>Add</th>
  <th>View</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
  <th>Edit</th>
  <th>All</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>Home</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="home.add"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="home.view"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="home.delete"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="home.edit"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="all-checkbox" data-target=".home-checkbox" value=".home-checkbox"></td>
  </tr>

// same will repeat for About and Contact.
```

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.all-checkbox').on('click', function() {
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
        $('input[name="permissions[]"][value^="' + target + '."]').prop('checked', isChecked);
        $('input[name="permissions[]"][value="' + target + '.view"]').prop('checked', true);
        if (isChecked) {
            $('input[name="permissions[]"][value="' + target + '.add"]').prop('checked', true);
            $('input[name="permissions[]"][value="' + target + '.edit"]').prop('checked', true);
            $('input[name="permissions[]"][value="' + target + '.delete"]').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('input[name="permissions[]"][value="' + target + '.add"]').prop('checked', false);
            $('input[name="permissions[]"][value="' + target + '.edit"]').prop('checked', false);
            $('input[name="permissions[]"][value="' + target + '.delete"]').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
    
    $('input[name="permissions[]"][value$=".add"], input[name="permissions[]"][value$=".delete"], input[name="permissions[]"][value$=".edit"]').on('click', function() {
        var target = $(this).val().split('.')[0];
        $('input[name="permissions[]"][value="' + target + '.view"]').prop('checked', true);
    });
});
</script>
```

When I click add, edit, delete checkbox it is check the view checkbox automatically. Its working fine, but when I click "ALL" checkbox it should check the all the checkbox automatically. I tried all the possible ways but it is not working.

Comment: You are looking for checkbox that has the value of `.home-checkbox` but none have this

Comment: Either remove `-checkbox` or do `$(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=checkbox]").not(this)` to get all the checkbox assosiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, find the closest `<tr>` and set the checkbox's checked property to checked property of clicked `.all-checkbox`. You can follow the following sample code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tbody").find('.all-checkbox').off("click").on('click', function() {
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
        $(this).closest("tr").find("[type='checkbox']").prop('checked',isChecked);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="pagePermissions">Page Permissions:</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Menu Page</th>
        <th>Add</th>
        <th>View</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>All</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Home</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="home.add">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="home.view">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="home.delete">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="home.edit">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="all-checkbox" data-target=".home-checkbox" value=".home-checkbox">
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Hi Kiran, Its working fine now!